# Map data in table rows to properties in Doctrine2 objects

Tags: php, hibernate, doctrine-orm

We are currently considering migrating our database code in php to Doctrine2. It seems to us that most of the things we would like the do are possible with Doctrine2. There is only one thing which we are not sure if it is possible and how we should do that. Our database model can't be changed right now because another project is using the same database. We can only change one thing at a time. Of course we are also curious how to improve the database model but that is not our main concern.

The issues is like this. We have a product table containing basic product information like this:

```
[product_id | code         | name          | description              | price]
 4            AS84GD         Steel brush    Strong steel brush.....     25.50
 28           HDD21N         Sand paper     Sand paper for wood.....     0.40
```

etc

We have different users for our product which al have different extra product properties. So we have an product_extra_field table which could look like this:

```
[extra_field_id | name]
 3                weight
 4                color
 9                supplier
```

and finally the table with the extra data product_extra_field_data

```
[product_id | extra_field_id | value]
 4            3                280
 4            4                brown
 4            9                company_x
 28           3                3
 28           4                yellow
 28           9                company_y
```

How do we right the necessary Doctrine2 code to get this data in one object, so we could have an object like this?

```
[Product]
Id : 4
Code : AS84GD
Name : Steel brush
Description : Strong steel brush.....
Price : 25.50
Weight : 280
Color : brown
Supplier : company_x
```

I've added a tag for Hibernate because I can read (N)Hibernate code and translate the ideas to Doctrine2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I don't think you can achieve that with [mapped superclasses](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html).

But, you could use native SQL within the doctrine result set mapping:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Those are one of the drawbacks when mapping between objects and relational data, I mean, if you really want just one entity instead of replicating the relationships from the database.

Comment: I think you mean this part http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#named-native-query? Does Doctrine2 generate the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements based on the SELECT statement?

Comment: @munnik I've never used this one, only this: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#resultsetmappingbuilder in order to retrieve objects, not to update/insert. But, maybe the `Named Native Query` can handle that, not sure, you have to test it. Let me know if it works. I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

You could create several classes:
- Product
- ExtraField
- ExtraFieldValue

With the following relations:
One Product has many ExtraFields (One To Many relation), one ExtraField has many ExtraFieldValues (One To Many relation), consedering your DB structure.

Then you have to customize your getters/setters to get only the first result of the collections (if in fact your relations are One To One)...

Don't know if I'm clear enough.

Comment: It's clear but not what we want. We don't want to 'think' of the different tables in de the code. Just 1 product class which should have a sort of dynamic list of properties.